# Reading from Kafka with Scala Spark2 Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to connect to Kafka and read data from it (after that I have to write in ElasticSearch Database), but for now, I just want to read and print data..

I am newbie with both Kafka and Scala, and reading in internet I have coded this:

```
//spark
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

//kafka
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe



object Main extends App{

val master = "local[2]"
val hostname = ""

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaConnection").setMaster(master)
val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "IRC",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,  PreferConsistent,  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))

stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))

val offsetRanges = Array(
  // topic, partition, inclusive starting offset, exclusive ending offset
  OffsetRange("test", 0, 0, 100),
  OffsetRange("test", 1, 0, 100)
)

val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String](
    ssc, kafkaParams, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)

}
```

But I don't know how to continue. What do I need now? Also, do you know any public Kafka Broker/topic which I can use to read from it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Spark Streaming is deprecated. Please use Structured Streaming https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Also, why Spark or Scala if you don't know them? https://www.confluent.io/blog/the-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using these because it is what they ask me in my company. Im still learning!

Comment: IMO, don't blindly trust and use things just because your company asked you to.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need now?

Try running the code. `spark-submit` or run the main method.

> do you know any public Kafka Broker/topic which I can use to read from it?

That would be insecure, so no. Start your own brokers locally following Kafka quickstart official guides.

Your code currently reads from a topic called `test`